# Cufon Asp.net in master page

Tags: asp.net, master-pages, cufon

I try to use Cufon fonts in my web page. I have master page and in head tag I have this:

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.4.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="js/cufon-yui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="js/cufon-replace.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="js/GeosansLight_500.font.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="js/Impact_400.font.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <link href="App_Themes/tDefault/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

and in the end of MasterPage before end body:

```
<script type="text/javascript">    Cufon.now();</script>
```

but in page i have this error: Webpage error details
Message: 'Cufon' is undefined
URI: http://localhost:93/en/

how can I embed this font in asp.net, is this correct way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the path to the JavaScript correct?

Answer (score 1):

In your header put

```
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
<asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" id="phHeader">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src='<%= ResolveUrl("~/js/cufon-yui.js") %>'></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src='<%= ResolveUrl("~/js/Myriad_Pro_400.font.js") %>'></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src='<%= ResolveUrl("~/js/cufon-replace.js") %>'></script>
 </asp:PlaceHolder>
</head>
```